# Zero a 2d array in C++. Do I need 2 for loops?

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I zero a 2D array in C++? Do I need two for loops just for that?

Coming from other higher languages, I wonder why C++ doesn't initialize arrays to meaningful/sensible defaults? Do I always need to declare an array then "zero" it out right afterwards?

Comment: No, you don't always have to zero it right after. That's why they aren't zeroed for you; it's a waste of time when you don't need it to be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C++ language tries to follow the principle of "you don't pay for what you don't use". It doesn't initialize fundamental types to any default values because you might not want it to happen. In any case, the language provides you the opportunity to explicitly request such initialization.

At the moment of declaration you can use initializers and simply do this

```
int array[10][20] = {};
```

or, for a dynamically allocated array

```
int (*array)[20] = new int[10][20]();
```

and this will give a zero-initialized array. No loops necessary.

But if you want to zero-out an existing array, then you will indeed have to use something more elaborate. In case of integer types a good old `memset` will work. For pointer or floating-point types the situation is in general case more complicated. `memset` might work or it might not work, depending on the implementation-defined properties. In any case, the standard library can help you to reduce the number of explicit loops by providing such loop wrappers as `std::fill`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how you create it.

Two-dimensional vector, yes, two for-loops (because integers are primitive types - classes will call the default ctor).

Two-dimensional array?  No, you can `memset` or `bzero` at once as the memory is all contiguous, whether using `malloc` or `new`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `memset` to put zeros everywhere. Documented [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/)

```
memset(pointer, value_to_put, num_bytes);
```

So in this case, you would have something along the lines of

```
memset(myArray, 0, sizeof(arrayElement) * width * height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only C-style arrays of scalar types have the option to be created without initialization. To initialize such an array to zero, you can just provide an empty initializer:

```
int a[3][3] = {}; // 3x3 zeroes
```

As you're coming from 'other higher languages', consider less low-level types for your 2D data (there are multiple matrix libraries: [boost.ublas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) and Eigen probably the most popular, and of course there are [multi-arrays](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html) in boost too)